# Display all values except the null reference object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, ado

I have a foreach loop that is pulling data from an XML file, however some fields are blank. When the loop tries to pull a specific value it will sometimes get a null reference exception. Is there a way to single out the variable that has the null value and set it to an empty string while displaying all the other values in an efficient way? For the sake of the example lets say the address field is returning the null value.

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(id);

        XmlNodeList person = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//parent/child");

        foreach (XmlNode node in person)
        {
            try
            {
                var name = node["name"].InnerText;
                var phone = node["phone"].InnerText;
                var email = node["email"].InnerText;
                var address = node["address"].InnerText;

                lblPopulate2.Text = name;
                lblPopulate7.Text = address;
                lblPopulate5.Text = phone;
                lblPopulate6.Text = email;
            }
            catch(NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                ???  
            }
            finally
            {
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) which would return null if the address node is not present, otherwise the `InnerText`.

```
var address = node["address"]?.InnerText;
```

And then the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) for setting your `Text` property:

```
lblPopulate7.Text = address ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: One line would work `lblPopulate7.Text = node["address"]?.InnerText ?? string.Empty`;

Comment: Thank you so much I had to to upgrade my C# language to 6 from 5 using nuget for this to work:
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform